# What is the value of $\left< e^{-|x|}\left| \left(i\frac{d} {dx}\right)^2 \right|e^{-|x|}\right> $?

Tags: expected-value, inner-products, positive-definite

**My approach:**

\begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
\left< e^{-|x|}\left| \left(i\frac{d}        {dx}\right)^2 \right|e^{-|x|}\right> &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|} \left(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)e^{-|x|}dx 
\\ 
&= -\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-|x|} \frac{d^2e^{-|x|}}{dx^2}dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-|x|} \frac{d^2 e^{-|x|}}{dx^2} dx\right]
\\
&= -\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{x} \frac{d^2e^{x}}{dx^2}dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{d^2 e^{-x}}{dx^2} dx\right]
\\
&= -\left[ \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2x}dx + \int _0^\infty e^{-2x} dx\right]
\\
&= -\left[ \frac{e^{2x}}{2}\right]_{-\infty}^0 - \left[\frac{e^{-2x}}{(-2)} \right]_0^\infty
\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}
\\
&= -1
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**But:**

\begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
\left< e^{-|x|}\left| \left(i\frac{d}        {dx}\right)^2 \right|e^{-|x|}\right> &= \left< e^{-|x|}\left| \left(i\frac{d}        {dx}\right)^\dagger \left(i\frac{d}        {dx}\right) \right|e^{-|x|}\right>
\\ 
&= \|\left(i\frac{d}{dx}\right) |e^{-|x|}\rangle \|^2
\\
&\gt 0
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**My Question:**

$1.$ What is wrong with my approach that I am getting a negative value?

$2.$ How to calculate $\left< e^{-|x|}\left| \left(i\frac{d}        {dx}\right)^2 \right|e^{-|x|}\right>$?

Comment: In your first approach, you can use the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}e^{-|x|}=-|x|'e^{-|x|}$. The derivative of $|x|$ is $2H(x)-1$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. The derivative of $H(x)$ is Dirac's delta, $\delta(x)$. All these are in the distributional sense

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is that $\frac d{dx} e^{-|x|}$ has a discontinuity at $0$. Then $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{-|x|}$ is not finite. So you can't ignore it when you calculate the integrals.
2. I suggest you integrate by parts. $$f(x)=e^{-|x|}\\g(x)=\frac d{dx}e^{-|x|}$$
   Then use $$\int fg'dx=fg-\int f'g dx$$
   You can then apply your approach and split the integral into positive and negative, since the integrand is finite around $0$.

Comment: Since I have included zero as a limit after splitting the integral, in what sense have I ignored the discontinuity at $0$. Under what condition can I break the integral?

Comment: You have a case where you integrate a [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). This is a special "function" that is zero everywhere except at $0$, but has the property that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)dx=1$